# backend awsmobile project creation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

I'm trying to create a project with react native and AWS but after put the credentials with "awsmobile configure" command I got this error below with "awsmobile init".

```
the security token included in the request is invalid

{ UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.at Object.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, you may want to try running `aws configure` *outside* of a valid awsmobile project.  This will ensure that the accessKeyId, secretAccessKey and region you enter are applied to all projects you initiate.